# FormArray total of each formgroup via RxJS

Tags: typescript, angular-2+, rxjs

Stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-plp4rb-formarray-total-prs9ay

I'm new to RxJS observables.

I've created a form array where the total for a line is `quantity * rate`. Via `valueChanges` for the line form group I set the total via the `calcTotal` method.

On form changes I emit all the lines up to parent to calculate the total.

**Questions:**

1. Do I have any memory leaks?
2. Why is it if I stick `debounceTime(1)` inside the lineItem valueChanges then this stops working where the calculation is out by the last change?

```
    lineItem.valueChanges.pipe(
      takeUntil(this.destroyed$),
      debounceTime(1)
    ).subscribe(value => this.calcTotal(lineItem))
```

3. Why is it if I remove the `{emitEvent: false}` and put in a `debounceTime` as above the total stops working altogether?
4. Should i be using some other way like `combineLatest`? If so how do I collect the valueChanges observables (I'll figure it out from here if this is required)?

````
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormArray, FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms'
import { Subject } from 'rxjs'
import { takeUntil, debounceTime} from 'rxjs/operators'
import { MatTable } from '@angular/material';

import { Line } from '../app.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-total-calculator',
  templateUrl: './total-calculator.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./total-calculator.component.css']
})
export class TotalCalculatorComponent implements OnInit {
  displayedColumns = ['quantity', 'rate', 'total'];
  formGroup: FormGroup;

  @Input() lines: Line[];
  @Output() linesChange = new EventEmitter<Line[]>();
  @ViewChild(MatTable) private matTable: MatTable<any>;

  get linesArray(): FormArray {
   return this.formGroup.get('lines') as FormArray;
  }

  private destroyed$ = new Subject<void>();

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
   this.buildForm();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
   this.destroyed$.next();
   this.destroyed$.complete();
  }

  addLineClick() {
    this.addLineFormGroup();
  }

  addLineFormGroup() {
    this.linesArray.push(this
      .getLineFormGroup());
    this.matTable.renderRows();
  }

  private buildForm() {
     // formarray
     this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
       lines: this.fb.array([])
     });

     // subscribe to any changes and emit these
     this.formGroup.valueChanges.pipe(
       takeUntil(this.destroyed$),
       debounceTime(300)
     ).subscribe(value => {
        if (!this.formGroup.valid) {
          return;
        }
        this.linesChange.emit(value['lines']);
    });
  }

  getLineFormGroup(): FormGroup {
    let lineItem = this.fb.group({
      quantity: new FormControl(),
      rate: new FormControl(),
      total: new FormControl()
    });
    lineItem.valueChanges.pipe(
      takeUntil(this.destroyed$),
    ).subscribe(value => this.calcTotal(lineItem))
    return lineItem
  }

  calcTotal(line: FormGroup) {
    const quantity =  +line.controls['quantity'].value;
    const rate =      +line.controls['rate'].value;  
    line.controls['total'].setValue((quantity * rate).toFixed(2), {emitEvent: false});
  }



  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Do I have any memory leaks?

```
No
```

2. Why is it if I stick debounceTime(1) inside the lineItem valueChanges then this stops working where the calculation is out by the last change?

> Beacuse debounceTime(1) delays the response by 1ms inside the lineItem
>   and `this.linesChange.emit(value['lines']);`  is already run with old
>   total

The implementation below will sort your problems.

```
  getLineFormGroup(): FormGroup {
    let lineItem = this.fb.group({
      quantity: new FormControl(),
      rate: new FormControl(),
      total: new FormControl()
    });
    lineItem.valueChanges.pipe(
      takeUntil(this.destroyed$),
      debounceTime(20)
    ).subscribe(value => 
      { 
        console.log("should be called first")
        this.calcTotal(lineItem)

        if (!this.formGroup.valid) {
          return;
        }
        this.linesChange.emit(this.formGroup.value['lines']);
      }
    )
    return lineItem
}
```

3. Why is it if I remove the {emitEvent: false} and put in a debounceTime as above the total stops working altogether?

> The lineItem.valueChanges observable will fire in a circular fashion
>   when you remove this {emitEvent: false}.
>   line.controls['total'].setValue() will fire lineItem.valueChanges
>   again. Which in-turn crashes the app and stop.

4. Should i be using some other way like combineLatest? If so how do I collect the valueChanges observables (I'll figure it out from here if this is required)?

> I would suggest not required